# Get user group as string in django

Tags: python, django

Need to know how to get the django user model group as a string in django, i mean :

```
request.user.groups.get
```

Returns me an object, but i need to get the exact string name of the group for example "administrators", or "sales" in order to compare it inside a conditional.

And what if i have many groups ?, how do i get the specified index ?

I tried :

```
request.user.groups.get(0)
```

or

```
request.user.group.get[0]
```

But it doesn't work.

Thanks for your help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a better one now :

```
lista= request.user.groups.all()[0].name
```

Answer (score 2):

To get all groups of a user, you could do:

`groups = request.user.groups.all()`

`groups` is a `ManyToManyField` to `User` model, and `.all()` is how to access all m2m objects. Please look at [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) for more m2m details.

To get the group as string you could either do `group.name` or `str(group)`.